# Does Factory Reset return to ORIGINAL firmware or to the last working firmware. (TPLINK ac1200 router)

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

on my router i upgraded the firmware to dd wrt
now i hit the factor reset button and expected it to go back to the 'factory ui' etc
but i still see dd wrt there

on electronic devices like routers,  are there 2 memories for firmware?
1 for the original factory FW
2. for the current working FW

If there is only one location to store firmware, is why devices can be 'bricked'?

Comment: My observation is that more and more manufacturers are building both Computers and Routers with firmware to recover from issues however caused.  I have had my X1 latop recover from a failed BIOS (UEFI) update and my Cisco RV345 router recover from a failed firmware.  Both devices carried on after recovery. You need to check the manual for your device.

Comment: You should assume that a "*Factory Reset*" refers primarily to the configuration settings, rather than any firmware version.

Comment: @sawdust . what do you mean by that. if i install ddwrt over my routers factory console UI.. doesnt that mean i updated the firmware.  now if i hit factory reset button what configuation settings are you referring to ?  thanks

Comment: Configuration data would include the login username & password, and all the other device settings for WAN, LAN, and WLAN. IOW the data that can be modified using the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

Many devices can hold two firmwares but they are the current and previous versions to allow a failed upgrade to recover to the previous working one.

Many other devices hold only one copy and a power fail at the wrong time will brick the device.

There may be some that also hold the original factory version but I don’t know if any.

Comment: Even for those still relatively rare devices with backup firmware, recovering to any official firmware isn't possible after using DD-WRT or any other alternative firmware.